# How is semaphore queue protected with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, binary-semaphore

In one of the interviews I was asked...

```
Wait(semaphore sem) {                           
   DISABLE_INTS
   sem.val--
   if (sem.val < 0){
      add thread to sem.L
      block(thread)
    }
ENABLE_INTS
```

The above is the semaphore wait implementation (copied from other thread).
How is the queue sem.L protected when multiple threads try to enqueue (when they fail to get the lock) ? Do we take lock before updating the queue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation for a system with only a single core. Concurrency is managed by disabling interrupts during critical sections. That's what the "DISABLE_INTS" and "ENABLE_INTS" are in that code.

Unless you were interviewing for a position developing multi-tasking operating system code for single-core systems, it's a strange question to ask. Perhaps the interviewer was expecting you to ask questions about the code and see if you could understand under what circumstances this would make sense.

Conflict can only occur with code running on this core or another core. Since there's only one core, the only possible conflict is with code running on this care. That would require a context switch.

Context switches come in two forms, voluntary and involuntary. A voluntary context switch occurs when code explicitly asks for one. This code doesn't ask for a context switch, so that's not an issue. An involuntary context switch can only be triggered by an interrupt, and this code disables interrupts in its critical section. This was a typical way "locks" were implemented in kernel code for single core systems.

Comment: Sorry... My question is, when we don't get the lock, we try to add the calling process to the queue.  How is that queue synchronized.  Do we take a lock for that queue ?

Comment: David already explained that. With only one core, and interrupts disabled, a lock is not required because the code cannot be interrupted and then reentered.  I you don't understand David's answer, you need some further knowledge of computer architecture and OS kernel functionality.

Comment: @SureshChowta It's synchronized against accesses from other cores because there are no other cores. It's synchronized against other code running on this same core by disabling interrupts -- with interrupts disabled, there's no possibility of a context switch because only an interrupt can trigger an involuntary context switch. Understanding this requires understanding of how concurrency is managed at a low level -- not knowledge a typical programmer with no kernel coding experience would have. It's a bad question to ask someone who wouldn't be expected to have kernel development knowledge.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz
Thank you for trying to make me understand.
Why are we talking about single core only here.  My code or the implementation doesn't mention anything about that.  Isn't it ?
What happens in case of multi-core system where some other thread running on a different core is trying to enqueue to the same Q.

Comment: @SureshChowta "*My code or the implementation doesn't mention anything about that.*" It does by treating the disabling of interrupts as if it was a lock, which only works on single core systems. "*What happens in case of multi-core system where some other thread running on a different core is trying to enqueue to the same Q?*" We use different code appropriate for that situation. Since this code is not appropriate for that situation, we wouldn't use it if we were in that situation.

Comment: Thank you @DavidSchwartz
I think, I copied the wrong example code for semaphore.  Can you please let me know what happens in the other case where there are multiple cores and ignoring the statements about interrupts.

Comment: @SureshChowta What happens when you put a car on the moon and ignore the engine? That really doesn't make sense. This code uses disabling of interrupts to prevent pre-emption and it's made for use on a single-core system only. If you change it or use it in conditions it's not made for, it will fail.